# How to query post into a complex slider

Tags: wp-query, query

I'm trying to query post into a slider. Here is the HTML Markup for the slider. Each slide has slide and a relating thumbnail.

```
 <div id="example1" class="slider-pro">
    <div class="sp-slides">
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif"
                 data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg"
                 data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg"/>
             <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                data-position="bottomLeft"
                data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                1st slide Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametayyyyyeee <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif"
                data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg"
                data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg"/>
             <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                data-position="bottomLeft"
                data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                2nd slide Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametayyyyyeee <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif"
                data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg"
                data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_large.jpg"/>
             <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                data-position="bottomLeft"
                data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                3rd slide Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametayyyyyeee <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif"
                data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_medium.jpg"
                data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_large.jpg"/>
            <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                data-position="bottomLeft"
                data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                4th slide Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametayyyyyeee <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif"
                data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_medium.jpg"
                data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image5_large.jpg"/>
             <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                data-position="bottomLeft"
                data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                5th slide Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametayyyyyeee <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sp-thumbnails">
        <div class="sp-thumbnail">
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">1st slide Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">1Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-thumbnail">
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">2nd slide Do eiusmod</div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">2 Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-thumbnail">
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">3rd slide Ut enim</div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">3 Ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-thumbnail">
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">4th slide Ullamco oris</div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">4 Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sp-thumbnail">
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">5th slide Duis aute</div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">5 Irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I came up with but its not working. The 'sp-thumbnail' elements are repeating [Heres a screen shot](http://dev.zumic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Screenshot-2015-03-17-12.10.08.png)

```
       <?php
        $args = array( 
             'post_type' => array('post', 'music-videos'),
             'posts_per_page' => 5,
             'orderby'  => 'menu_order post_date',
              );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>

        <div id="example1" class="slider-pro">
            <div class="sp-slides">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="sp-slide">
                      <div class="sp-image">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related-thumb' ); ?>
                    </a>
                  </div>


                 <p class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                    data-position="bottom"
                    data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                     <span class="hide-small-screen" style="font-size:1.75em    ;"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnails">
                <div class="sp-thumbnail">
                    <div class="sp-thumbnail-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: What's the question?  Please provide some detail as to what is failing.

Comment: `wp_reset_query` is only to be used after `query_posts`, which you should never use. Perhaps you meant ot use `wp_reset_postdata`. Also, you said it isn't working, but you didn't say how, can you edit your question to include details on what happened and how it differs from what you expected?

Comment: Updated with more details.

Comment: For the images, ``the_post_thumbnail();`` outputs the whole ``img`` tag. So you don't need the ``<img src="... ``

Comment: @jzatt you're right changed the <img and the images are working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
      <?php
        $args = array( 
             'post_type' => array('post', 'music-videos'),
             'posts_per_page' => 5,
             'orderby'  => 'menu_order post_date',
              );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <div id="example1" class="slider-pro">
            <div class="sp-slides">
                <div class="sp-thumbnails" >
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="sp-slide">
                <div class="sp-image">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related-thumb' ); //the_post_thumbnail( 'col-4-img-thumb' ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                 <div class="sp-layer sp-black sp-padding" 
                    data-position="bottom"
                    data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="down">
                    <span class="hide-small-screen" style="font-size:1.75em;"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sp-thumbnail">
                <div class="sp-thumbnail-title"><?php the_title(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```